# Is GHashTable (glib2) thread safe?

Tags: c, thread-safety, glib

I have multiple threads adding, modifying and looking up data in GHashTable.
Is it threadsafe, or do I need to implement threadsafety myself?

Comment: why someone would vote up this question as too localized ? This is good, reasonable and fair question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html) states this pretty clearly:

> After calling `g_thread_init()`, GLib is completely thread safe (all global data is automatically locked), but individual data structure instances are not automatically locked for performance reasons. So, for example you must coordinate accesses to the same `GHashTable` from multiple threads.

So: no, the hash table is not thread safe.